# The variance of a simple random walk/process

Tags: stochastic-processes, random, random-walk

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for the past day. Please help!

Let $\epsilon_i = \pm 1$ with equal probabilities independently for $i=1,...,N$.
Then $Z_i = \epsilon_1 + ... + \epsilon_i$ is a random walk. $Z_i$ is a random walk process for $i = 1, ..., N$.

Why is the variance $var(\epsilon_i) = 1$ and $var(Z_i) = i$ ?

Comment: Well first off, by symmetry, it is clear the mean of both is 0.

Comment: @PyRulez yup, so $E[Z_i\] = 0$ and $var(Z_i) = E[(Z_i - E[Z_i\])^2]$ right?

Answer (score 6):

we know the mean $E[\epsilon_j]$=0

so the variance $E[\epsilon_j^2] - (E[\epsilon_j])^2$ is $E[\epsilon_j^2]$ which is 1

due to independence

$var(Z_i)=\sum_{j=1}^i var(\epsilon_j)=\sum_{j=1}^i 1 = i$

Answer (score 4):

Since the $\{\epsilon_i\}$ are independent:
$var(Z_i)=\sum_{j=1}^ivar(\epsilon_j) =i$.

Answer (score 1):

For the $\epsilon_i$ there are only two possibilities: $1$ and $-1$. As noted, the mean is $0$.

$\therefore var(\epsilon_i)=\frac12\left((1-0)^2+(-1-0)^2\right)=1 $

Comment: Yes but how about for $var(Z_i)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know. This was just a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a more intuitive way to see this, if you express the simple Random walk in terms of the **Bernoulli random variable** (which is considered the most basic random variable that exists).

Let's mark this Bernoulli Random Variable as $X_i$, where $X_i=1$ with probability $0.5$ and $X_i=0$ with probability $0.5$.

First note that $\epsilon_i$ can be actually expressed in terms of $X_i$:

$$\epsilon_i = 2X_i -1$$

You should double check the above expression to satisfy yourself that it holds true (if $X_i = 0$, indeed $\epsilon_i = -1$, and if $X_i = 1$, indeed $\epsilon_i = 1$).

Now it is super simple. $Z_i = \sum_{j=1}^{i} \left( 2X_i -1 \right) = 2* \sum_{j=1}^{i} (X_i) - i  $.

$$ Var(Z_i) = Var\left( 2* \sum_{j=1}^{i} (X_i) - i \right) = 4\sum_{j=1}^{i} Var(X_i)$$

Now $Var(X_i)$ for the Bernoulli random variable is just $p*(1-p)$. Since $p=0.5$, then $Var(X_i)=0.25$. Therefore:

$$4\sum_{j=1}^{i} Var(X_i) = \sum_{j=1}^{i} 4 * 0.25 = \sum_{j=1}^{i} 1 = i $$